# printing prime numbers between 0 and 100 in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to print prime numbers between 0 and 100 but my code ends up giving 2,3 and every number from 5 to 99. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
 void main()
{
    int n=0,i=2,flag;
    while(n<=100){
        if(n<2){flag=0;}
        else if(n==2 || n==3){printf("%d\n",n);}
        else{
            while(i<=sqrt(n)){
                if(n%i==0){flag=0;break;}
                else{flag=1;}
                i++;//at this point no. is prime
            }
            if(flag==1){printf("%d\n",n);}
        }
        n++;
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to reset `i = 2;` for each case.

Comment: What should the value of `i` be _just before_ `while(i<=sqrt(n))`?

Comment: Have you stepped through the code in your debugger? That would definitely show you what’s going wrong, without you having to beg  other people to help.

Comment: BTW instead of dealing with values less than 4 *inside* the loop, you could start the loop at `4` (or `5`) after `printf("2\n3\n");`

Answer (score 0):

Rather than testing inside the loop for `n==2 || n==3`, you should just print the values `2` and `3` outside the loop, and start the loop at 5. Since no even numbers are prime after 2, only  test odd numbers starting at 5. And you need to start testing for factors starting at `i=3` (since you know they're not even you don't have to test 2). And you shouldn't check the value of `flag` (for primality) until the i-loop is done.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("2\n3\n");
    for (int n = 5; n <= 100; n+= 2) {
        int flag = 1;
        for (int i = 3; i <= sqrt(n); ++i) {
            if (n % i == 0) {
                flag = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (flag == 1)
            printf("%d\n",n);
    }
}
```